# GKE Kubernetes HOW to Proxy SELECT Queries from POD to read replicas

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

I have multiple SQL Read-only replicas setup on my GCP environment. I have two requirements.

1. Loadbalance select queries from my app pod to multiple read-only replicas.
2. Read-Replicas can increase/decrease and i want to keep this logic separate from application.

Comment: Are you using CloudSQL?

Comment: yes using CloudSQL

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#rr_lb):

> **Does Cloud SQL provide load balancing for requests to read replicas?**
>
> Cloud SQL does not automatically provide or configure load balancing. You can use [connection pooling](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections) to distribute read requests between read replicas by switching between multiple connection endpoints.

Thus there isn't a build-in way to achieve the logic you are searching for in Cloud SQL. This means that it might need to be programmed on the logic of the application that you use to manage your connections to Cloud SQL.